# Alternative method for setTimeout in Angular

Tags: angular

I am currently working on Angular project which is new to me. I have a requirement where I need to set a kendo dropdown value to it's default state after selecting an option.

.ts file

```
griddefaultItem = { text: 'Grid Actions', value: '' };
gridActions = [
{ text: 'Customize Grid Display', value: 'CGD' },
{ text: 'Download Grid To Excel', value: 'DGE' }
];

gridDisplay(obj: OptionalList) {
setTimeout(() => {
  this.gridselectedValue = this.griddefaultItem[0];
}, 10);
if (obj.value === 'CGD') {
  this.gridActionValue = true;
  this.getPopupDef();
  this.getPopupDetails();
}
}
```

html

```
<kendo-dropdownlist data-test-id="GA_B" [data]="gridActions" [defaultItem]="griddefaultItem" [textField]="'text'"
  [valueField]="'value'" (selectionChange)="gridDisplay($event)" [(value)]="gridselectedValue" class="dropdown_list"
  [popupSettings]="{ width: 170 }">
</kendo-dropdownlist>
```

Here, I am trying to set the default item after selecting an option from dropdown. When using setTimeout it is working but I got a review not to use it. Is there any alternative way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Why would you want to reset the value to default after the user selects an option?

Comment: @MichaelD, Also, it just shouldn't work properly. In `setTimeout` callback, he or she tries to get `this.griddefaultItem[0]`, but this isn't an array, it's just an object: `griddefaultItem = { text: 'Grid Actions', value: '' };`

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following instead of calling `setTimeout`:

- Set `gridselectedValue` to the new value
- Call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges`
- Set `gridselectedValue` to the default value

```js
constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

gridDisplay(obj: { text: string; value: string }) {
  this.gridselectedValue = obj;                   // <-- set new selected value
  this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();         // <-- run change detection
  this.gridselectedValue = this.griddefaultItem;  // <-- reset selected value
  // Do more processing here...
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pscdpt?file=app/app.component.ts) for a demo.